# Jquery hover dropdown menu closing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an issue with jQuery slideToggle on hover. Lets say I have 2 nav-item in the navigation container. Each has its own sub-menu items. Everything is working fine, but if someone starting to "Monkey test" it, then there come up some issues. One of it, when the mouse is not on the navigation container (`<nav>`) the menu is still open.

the HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul class="navigation lvl-1">
        <li>
            Menu1
            <ul class="sub-menu lvl-2">
                <li>Submenu1-1</li>
                <li>Submenu1-2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Menu2
            <ul class="sub-menu lvl-2">
                <li>Submenu2-1</li>
                <li>Submenu2-2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and here is the JS file (partial):

```
$('nav ul.lvl-1 > li').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('.lvl-2').not(':animated').slideToggle(300);
});
```

Comment: when the mouse is not on the navigation container (<nav>) the menu is still open at First Time?

Comment: @HeadInCloud No. it is working fine, but when the user started to flicker it like a crazy , then has that 'issue'

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
$('nav ul li').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(300);
});
```

```css
nav ul li ul{
  display:none;
  }

nav ul{
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<nav>
    <ul class="navigation lvl-1">
        <li>
            Menu1
            <ul class="sub-menu lvl-2">
                <li>Submenu1-1</li>
                <li>Submenu1-2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            Menu2
            <ul class="sub-menu lvl-2">
                <li>Submenu2-1</li>
                <li>Submenu2-2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```